# Wrong column mapping of pandas DataFrame from dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, mapping

I am trying to map 2 DataFrames

`L1`

```
ship  city   code  

 NaN   aa      12    
 NaN   bb      23    
 NaN   cc      13    
 NaN   dd      43
```

`B1`

```
 ship  city    
 
 21     dd     
 32     bb      
 43     aa      
 654    cc      
 34     bb     
 54     aa
```

I want to map column `code` from `L1` to `B1`. I tried mapping using a dictionary, so I would get a result like this

`Expected_Result =`

```
ship  city   code  
 
 21    dd      43    
 32    bb      23    
 43    aa      12    
 654   cc      13    
 34    bb      23    
 54    aa      12



 code_dict = dict(zip(L1['city'],L1['code'])) 
 B1['code'] = L1['city'].map(code_dict)
 print(B1)
```

The result that I got is not what I expected.

Please help me fix this issue.

```
 ship  city    code  
 
 21    dd       12    
 32    bb       23    
 43    aa       13    
 654   cc       43    
 34    bb       NaN   
 54    aa       NaN
```

Comment: L1 and B1 do not have a common `code` column? is this typo? are you joining this based on the city? if so then `21    dd      43 ` seems correct result.

Comment: Each city has a unique "code" associated with it, I have mapped it into a dictionary -"code_dict". Mapping/copying "code" corresponding to each "city" from "L1" to "B1" is what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: then this would work for you `l1.merge(b1,on=['city'],how='inner')[['ship_y','city','code']].rename({"ship_y":"ship"},axis=1)`

Comment: My actual dataset has many more columns, I will have to rename every duplicate column if I merge. Could you suggest a solution using dictionary or without having to rename columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options.

data setup:

```
ship=[np.nan]*4
city=['aa','bb','cc','ddd']
code=[12,23,13,43]

ship2=[21,32,43,654,34,54]
city2=['dd','bb','aa','cc','bb','aa']

l1=pd.DataFrame({"ship":ship,"city":city,"code":code})
b1=pd.DataFrame({"ship":ship2,"city":city2})
```

1st through **merge** on city:

```
l1.merge(b1,on=['city'],how='inner')[['ship_y','city','code']].rename({"ship_y":"ship"},axis=1)
```

2nd use map/dictionary:

```
ship_city_d = dict(zip(l1.city, l1.code)) # build the dictionary
b1['code']=b1['city'].apply(lambda x: str(ship_city_d.get(x,"Not Found")) )
```

**note:** b1 will have some entries if key not found, you can drop those record as next step if not needed.

Comment: Thank you `simpleApp` the 2nd approach was exactly what I was looking for, you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame


df1 = DataFrame([
    {'city': 'aa', 'code': 12},
    {'city': 'bb', 'code': 23},
    {'city': 'cc', 'code': 13},
    {'city': 'dd', 'code': 43}
])

df2 = DataFrame([
    {'ship': '21', 'city': 'dd'},
    {'ship': '32', 'city': 'bb'},
    {'ship': '43', 'city': 'aa'},
    {'ship': '654', 'city': 'cc'},
    {'ship': '34', 'city': 'bb'},
    {'ship': '54', 'city': 'aa'}
])

expected_result = df2.merge(df1, on='city')
print(expected_result)
```

Result:

```
  ship city  code
0   21   dd    43
1   32   bb    23
2   34   bb    23
3   43   aa    12
4   54   aa    12
5  654   cc    13
```

Comment: `expected_result = df2.merge(df1, on='city')
print(expected_result)` when I tried this, I got a duplicate column for "ship". Now I have two new columns `ship_x` (with values) and `ship_y` with (with only Nan values)